# Visual studio hints to download rc2 packages instead of rc1

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, nuget

Some time ago I tried to migrate to Asp.net RC2 from RC1 with my .net project using these instructions:

"To migrate to RC2, add the https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/ feed in your NuGet settings, run dnvm upgrade -u to use the latest DNX runtime and replace rc1-final by * in your project.json"

Later I abandoned this Idea. I deleted the feed from nuget settings, set dnx runtime to rc1-final, deleted nuget cache, but Visual Studio still shows me a hint with rc2 versions of packages whenever I want to download missing libs. It happens even in entirely new projects. How to make VS to hint me only rc1-final versions of packages?

[VS hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGHO4.png)

Comment: Ok, I found a solution. Deleting C:\Users\USER\.dnx\packages did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. Deleting C:\Users\USER\ .dnx\packages did the trick